# mysql- fetch values for unique email ids

Tags: mysql

The database table where I have to run this query has redundant email ids stored. Table stores `emailid` and `clientid`. But `clientid` is always unique as it's a primary key auto incremented field

I want to fetch all `clientid` for unique email id.

Let's say info@info.com is used for 2 different users. I want to exclude one of them. Let's say FCFS. I wanna include first email and exclude the next one.

This is the query that I wrote but it doesn't give me results with unique email id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (email), clientid 
FROM clients 
WHERE  status=1
```

Comment: Try `GROUP BY email` instead of `DISTINCT(email)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need it's the group by statement

```
 SELECT email, clientid 
    FROM clients 
    WHERE  status=1  
    GROUP BY email
```